# assigning one row of a two dimensional array to a one dimensional matrix

Tags: c++, gaussian

So I have a 2D array and I want to assign row 'pth' row of the 2D array to a new 1D array:
My code looks like this:

```
float temp[] = { *aMatrix[p] }; // aMatrix is  a 10x10 array
                                // am trying to assign the pth row
                                // to temp. 

*aMatrix[p] = *aMatrix[max];

*aMatrix[max] = *temp;

float t = bMatrix[p];
bMatrix[p] = bMatrix[max];
```

After the declaration above, temp should be of length 10 with all of the values of the pth 
row of aMatrix, but it contains just a value. I have tried all combos of that statement but
get nothing but compile errors..

My question is what is the correct way to make this assignment?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `*aMatrix[p]` gives you a single `float` - you're dereferencing twice. That makes `temp` an array of 1 float.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are confusing the pointers a bit. You can't copy all the members using a simple assignment. C++ does not support memberwise assignment of arrays. You should iterate through the elements like so:

```
float temp[10];

// copy the pth row elements into temp array.
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

   temp[i] = aMatrix[p][i]; 
}
```

You can also do it this second way if your aMatrix could possibly change lengths at some point:

```
int aLength = sizeof(aMatrix[p]) / sizeof(float);

float temp[aLength];

// copy the pth row elements into temp array.
for(int i=0; i < aLength; i++) {

   temp[i] = aMatrix[p][i]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was just beginning to think the same thing but was hoping there was a more elegan way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `std::array`? It is, unlike C-style arrays, assignable.

```
typedef std::array<float, 10> Row;

std::array<Row, 10> aMatrix;

Row temp = aMatrix[5];
```

Comment: Thanks. At this point in this assignment all the work is in place would have to make some major changes to implement that.